# Лучший способ указывать отдельные CSS правила для разных браузеров

Tags: css, кроссбраузерность, stylus

Так, как в разных браузерах, например, шрифты и отступы отображаются по-разному, нужно для каждого браузера указывать отдельное Css правило.

На данный момент использую следуее:

```
// IE9+
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)
    .div1
        transform scaleX(.7)

// Firefox
_:-moz-tree-row(hover), .div1
    transform scaleX(1)

//chrome
.selector:not(*:root), .div1
    transform scaleX(.4)
```

Есть ли лучший, более эффективный и компактный способ для этого? Есть ли еще специальные подобные правила, кроме этих трех, для других браузеров?

Comment: Нашел http://browserhacks.com возможно, замерить для `IE` на `@media screen and (min-width:0\0)` - будет ли лучше?
Очень желательно как-то заменить `*` для chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Отдельные файлы для каждого браузера и их подключение через JavaScript

Я бы сделал отдельный css-файл для каждого браузера, затем с помощью JavaScript [определял браузер клиента](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript), затем с помощью JavaScript [подключал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) соответствующий файл (по сути создаём тэг `link`).

Если правил не так и много, то можно с помощью JavaScript создать тэг `style` и его контент (предварительно определив браузер клиента).

#### Чистый CSS: условные стили для браузера (хаки)

Если не желаете связываться с JavaScript, есть интересное решение в рамках CSS  на [англ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577781/1548895).

Суть его в том, что вы указываете стили для каждого браузера инвидувиально через вендорные префиксы, `@media` или `@supports`:

Под `.selector` подразумевается нужный вам селектор.

```
/* Chrome 28+ */
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Firefox (любой) */
_:-moz-tree-row(hover), .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Internet Explorer 11+ */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Internet Explorer 10+ */
_:-ms-lang(x), .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Также Internet Explorer 10+ */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  /* Нужные стили */
}

/* Internet Explorer 9+ */
_::selection, .selector { /* Нужные стили */ }

/* Safari 6.1+, Chrome для iOS */
@media screen and (min-color-index: 0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) { @media {
  /* Нужные стили */
}}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Само по себе хорошо и верно, но вряд ли следует так желать, когда отдельных правил для разных браузеров не так уж и много...(?)
Для немногих изменений, может, вполне приемлемо будет просто вписать группу браузер-ориентированных правил(?).

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, но дело еще в том, что архитектура проекта не особо хороша для таких динамических вещей. Есть несколько файлов `.styl`, которые собираются в один `.css` рабочий файл. В данном случае домешивать css в js будет в моем коде явным минусом, исходя из архитектуры проекта...

Comment: @CodeGust Единственное ещё могу предложить такое [решение на англ. SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/645216/1548895), но его не пробовал и оно подразумевает зависимость от третьесторонней библиотеки, о качестве которой мне ничего не известно. Также можете попытаться реализовать то же самое самому (я имею ввиду написать JavaScript, который применит селекторы, к примеру `.opera .class1`, для браузера Opera добавит селектор `.class1`).

Comment: Спасибо, в ссылке нашел решение для IE -`_::selection`, хотя `@media screen ...` решение выглядит надежнее. Еще хочу найти замену для `chromeium` - заменить `.selector:not(*:root)` на что-то без `*`.

Comment: @CodeGust Если вы нашли в ссылке то, что Вам подошло (при этом вы это ещё и протестировали), то добавьте Ваш ответ. Я бы к примеру это не добавлял потому что
 1. там нету, _по моему мнению_, изящных решений.
 2. вопросу и многим ответам более 6 лет.

Comment: @CodeGust Обновил ответ, вот условные стили для браузеров. Если вам подходит, можете отметить ответ, как принятый?

Comment: СпасиБо! А не подскажете, какая реальная разница между `_::selection` и `@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)` для `IE9+`?

Comment: @CodeGust Всё же для IE10+, а так, как я полагаю, разницы нет. Мы их используем как хак для определения браузера.

Answer (score 0):

А чем не вариант проверять браузер на стороне сервера, и подключать соответствующие стили? Либо собирать ваш `css` файл исходя из этого, удаляя отдельные строки(если файл собирается ДО генерирования страницы)/подключая отдельные `.styl` файлы(если файл собирается ВО ВРЕМЯ генерирования страницы).

Comment: На бэкенде тоже хороший вариант

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov вот и я так считаю, по мне вообще - идеальный. Гибкая логика, никаких ограничений, кои предоставляет css. Нет необходимости переключать стили на лету, имхо самое подходящее - разруливать такие вопросы на серверсайде

Comment: Спасибо, но, как писал выше, архитектура проекта не позволяет. Есть сборщик Gulp+WebPack, четкая структура модулей кода. 1модуль=1.styl файл,например. Все собирается в 1 .css файл. Поэтому я и ищу наилучший способ/хак задания отдельных правил для разных браузеров.