# column-count и перенос блоков. Нюанс с column-count

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Имеется контейнер `.block`, в котором размещены три блока `.item-block`. Контейнер необходимо разделить на две колонки, в первой из них будут два первых блока, во второй - соответственно, последний. При этом должно быть соблюдено условие: дивы с классом `.item-block` должны быть прямыми потомками `.block`.

Хотел реализовать с помощью `column-count`, но столкнулся с проблемой: последний `.item-block`переносится во вторую колонку не полностью - часть остается в первой. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли починить этот момент, и, если нет, есть ли альтернативные варианты реализации такого блока. Ссылка на пример в [кодпене](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/NbZbpe?editors=1100).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}
.block {
  column-count: 2;
}
.item-block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      3. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: всё таки с этой задачей масонри лучше справляется ,. но всё же https://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/XNLpBZ  и маленький мануал http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Может, пригодится: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608106/178988

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Кажется, получилось:

```
.item-block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

И полностью в сниппете:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}
.block {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
.item-block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      3. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Можно попробовать добавить

```
.item-block {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

но эффект несколько специфический...

PS: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/

Comment: @Игорь, но если скопипастить третий блок ещё раз, то во вторую колонку он отправится. Полагаю, причина в том, что первые два блока по высоте меньше третьего, а браузер не хочет делать первую колонку меньше второй.

Comment: да, наверное так и есть, вы правы. Увы, у меня последний блок больше, больше чем оба первых вместе взятые.

Comment: вроде бы да: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp

Comment: @Geyan, по идее - да, но, если не ошибаюсь, его используют (или использовали) для запрета разрыва колонок в Хроме, поскольку оно в такой роли работает тоже, а нужного свойства там просто не было.

Comment: @Игорь для article сделай height:0; вроде ОНО

Comment: @Geyan 1. Не вижу в его коде `article`... 2. Если это ответ, то ответом и пости.

Comment: @Игорь в codepen смотри : пример же там

Answer (score 12):

Избежать частичного переноса блоков можно если добавить им свойство `display: inline-block`. Пока что так, а потом и `break-inside` нормально начнет работать :)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}
.block {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
.item-block {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      3. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ваш ответ. Я, после некоторого времени, пришел к тому же выводу - `inline-block` решает проблему переноса, но добавляет другую - отступ снизу. Посмотрите, добавился отступ, подозреваю, что на величину, равную той части блока, что должна была оставаться в первой колонке...

Comment: что сказать, поддержка спеки css columns пока что не самая радужная, потому попробуйте посмотреть в сторону флексбокса, возможно необходимую раскладку получиться реализовать проще.

Answer (score 6):

## Если надо, чтобы элементы .item-block переносились

В принципе ответы уже есть благодаря ответам [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609205/220571) и [@SashaOmelchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608362/220571). Осталось только решить проблему с лишней высотой у контейнера.

Насколько я вижу это только проблема Chromium-браузеров (к примеру, Chrome). 
В Firefox и IE ответ [@SashaOmelchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608362/220571) работает без бага контейнера. Поэтому и применим для Chromium хак позволяющий применять стили только для него `@supports (-webkit-appearance:none)`. И подобным образом [можно подобрать хаки, с помощью которых можно задавать разметку для индивидуального браузера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/603024/220571).

Весь код

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.block {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}

.item-block:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Стили для Chrome */
@supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {
  .item-block {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      3. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Если надо, чтобы элементы `.item-block` переносились

Задайте для `.item-block` `display: flex;`.

Также чтобы задать отступы только между блоками и не затронуть последний `item-block` (чтобы не было `margin-bottom: 10px;` у последнего) задайте отступы вот так.

```
.item-block + .item-block {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Запускаемый пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

.block {
  column-count: 2;
}

.item-block {
  display: flex;
}

.item-block + .item-block {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="item-block">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      2. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </div>
    <div class="item-block">
      3. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```