# Расположить inline-блоки друг под другом в двух колонках

Tags: css

Имеется набор инлайн-блоков переменной высоты. Четным задано обтекание справа, нечетным - слева. Результат на картинке ниже.

До **блока 2** все расположилось как надо, затем **3 блок** должен был оказать слева, но зацепился за **1 блок** и после него блоки начали цеплятся друг за друга, и порядок нарушился.

Как расположить блоки в двух колонках, чтобы они не цепляли друг друга и заполняли колонки без пропусков?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```css
.property-group {
  border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 245px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.property-group:nth-child(odd) {
  float: left;
}
.property-group:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
}
.property-group__title {
  color: #757575;
}
.property-group__item {
  color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">1</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">2</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">3</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">4</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">5</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
  <div class="property-group"><div class="property-group__title">6</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div><div class="property-group__item">text</div></div>
</div>
```

Финальный результат необходим такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: bootstrap юзать можно? флексбокс?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin флексбокс устроит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разделение списка на несколько колонок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619955/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: @Vadizar правка, на мой взгляд исказила смысл вопроса, необходимо две колонки.  добавил образец для лучшего понимания

Comment: @while1pass посмотрите код лучшего ответа вот этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608316/%D0%9D%D1%8E%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81-%D1%81-column-count/608362#608362

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `display: flex;`

Вот полная документация: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я вижу тут 3 колонки

Comment: @teran это пример. Его можно адаптировать под любое количество колонок.

Comment: не получилось адаптировать под образец, возможно, я то-то не понимаю, добавил образец в вопрос

Comment: @while1pass обновил ответ.

Comment: почти, но как не ограничиваться высотой? при heigh: 100% все блоки выстраиваются в одну колонку. я понимаю, что могу подобрать высоту под свое количество блоков, но как-только добавится еще один непридусмотренный, он вылезет еще одной колонкой. а нужно именно две колонки

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось, благодаря совету [Sasha Omelchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/224820/sasha-omelchenko) из этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608316/%D0%9D%D1%8E%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81-%D1%81-column-count/608362#608362).

Для родительского контейнера необходимо задать свойство `column-count`

```css
.details {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    width: 400px;
}

.property-group {
    border: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="details">
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 100px;">1</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 50px;">2</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 200px;">3</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 70px;">4</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 100px;">5</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 90px;">6</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 40px;">7</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 110px;">8</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 100px;">9</div>
  <div class="property-group" style="height: 100px;">10</div>
</div>
```